# Tricking English installer to install on French Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, internationalization

I have a French client with the French version of Windows 10.  However, our Installshield-built installer is looking for C:\Users\username\Local Settings\Application Data, and fails with "Error 1320.  The specified path is too long"

We tried to see if we could connect to the appropriate Local Settings\Application Data folder (in English), but it is either not accessible or even as admin we don't have privileges to go there (even from an admin command line).

I understand Windows 10 has some sort of invisible aliases or compatibility for these standard folders?

Are there any tricks we could use to get the software installed?

Comment: If you are using the correct environmental variable (`%APPDATA%`) in the installer then this should work - are you sure that you haven't used a path that's at least partially hardcoded?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it does NOT use the correct environmental variable.  That's why I'm wondering if there's a way around the issue?

Comment: If it uses a hard coded path (even if only partially hard coded) then no, there's no way round it unless you want to rebuild the MSI.

Comment: Fix it to use the correct environmental variables instead of a hard-coded path. There is no way to hack your way around a non-existent folder; creating it wouldn't fix anything. Fix your installer.

Comment: Here's what's odd: our French end user ran our installer on a DIFFERENT machine with French Windows installed -- and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: this is a hack and the correct answer was provided by slugster - rebuild the MSI**

Now that that's out of the way I do have a suggestion for you that might be able to resolve the problem for you.  You can try creating the path that the installer is looking for and then creating a symlink to link that folder to the correct folder on the users machine.  no guarantee that this works but might be worth a shot.  If you need more info on creating symlinks check out hte TechNet page for [MkLink](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx)